# PHP 7 using javascript in if statement

Tags: php-7

In php 5.X this worked just fine.

```
if (empty ( $season )) {
    ?>
    <script type = 'text/javascript'>
    alert("Program Error - you must set a season");
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

In php 7 on Ubuntu 16.04  this generates a
**PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'break' (T_BREAK), expecting function (T_FUNCTION)**

I can remove the php end and start tags and use echo and wrap the test in heredoc syntax to get it working but then I lose the javascript text highlighting when using my favorite editor.

Is there a way to keep my current syntax in php7?

Comment: What line generates that? This is almost certainly a syntax error, or you have a hidden special character causing a problem.

Comment: The error message gets marked on whatever php statement follows the closing brace (})

Comment: Can you pls revise the example code to provide a fully-working (well: working on PHP 5 anyhow ;-) example. Also: what troubleshooting steps have you performed thusfar? DOes it mappter what text is within the if block, or is it specifically JS? Or specifically *that* JS? Light reading: http://sscce.org/ and http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: SSCCE I tested with: https://gist.github.com/adamcameron/0f25031089e0c0ff8e802daa752b45e2

Comment: Adam,  thank you for the code sample.  I never tested the if statement in question on its own.  My mistake. That has no syntax errors.  The code fragment is out of a large class file.  After your example, I extracted the function containing the if statement from the class.  That parses with no syntax errors.  So its something else in the class file causing the problem.  That is something for me to solve.    Thank you everyone for your feedback and sorry to have created a question that was not necessary.

Comment: I found the problem.   Earlier in the file there were a number of php blocks.  The one that started and contained the if statement with the above error was started by <?  not by <?php.   An important thing to look for when moving from php5 to php7.

Comment: I think you should probably elevate yer comment above to an "answer" though, as it is a handy reminder that sometimes one can focus on the wrong bit of one's code when troubleshooting. Everyone does it! Also a reminder about one of the breaking changes in PHP7. Good detective work!